# How can I know the total time that EBS Volume state is Available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ebs

I want to remove EBS that is available for a long time.

I want to remove EBS based on the total time available

Can I check using cloudwatch?
Is there no choice but to write code using lambda?
**How can I know the total time that EBS Volume state is Available or in-use?**

Comment: when it is available, is it attached to ec2 instance?

Comment: Can you tell us more about _why_ you want to do this? Are you trying to remove _unused_ EBS volumes?

Comment: When EBS is available, it is not attached to ec2 instance. 
I want to know how much time I'm wasting without using EBS. By doing so, I'm going to analyze how effective it is to remove EBS for cost savings.